# SMTP email attachment sending method?

Tags: email, smtp, email-attachments

If SMTP only allows 7-bit ASCII, how do we send pictures/videos/files via email?
Do we encode these objects as 7-bit ASCII? Or basacally we can't send attachments via SMTP protocol?

Comment: given that binary attachments are being sent by the billions every day using SMTP, perhaps you should be asking "How" instead of "can we". e.g. start reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can attach binary files to email messages and send these using SMTP.

The solution is to use MIME and encode the files. One common encoding used is base64.